# sql server replication - how to get combination of values from a binary(8) field?

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication, varbinary

I am using the table [sysschemaarticles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182785.aspx) to collect information in my transactional replication.

It is used for a variety of things including adding new articles and finding out who are the subscriber Servers.

this script needs to be run in the publication database.

```
SELECT  
 PublisherDB=db_name()  
,PublisherName=sp.name
,The_Type=so.type_desc
,The_Schema=schema_name(so.schema_id)
,The_Object=sa.name
,SubscriberServerName=UPPER(srv.srvname)  
,so.is_schema_published
,so.is_published
,sa.schema_option
from dbo.syspublications sp  
INNER JOIN dbo.sysschemaarticles sa on sp.pubid = sa.pubid 
INNER JOIN sys.objects so on sa.objid = so.object_id
INNER JOIN dbo.syssubscriptions s on sa.artid = s.artid 
INNER JOIN master.dbo.sysservers srv on s.srvid = srv.srvid
```

[image]

However the schema_option has different options that can be associated with it, and I would like to figure out ALL of them.

You can see the possible options on the picture below.

[image]

How can I get ALL the values stored in a binary(8) field?

I believe there could be a combination of options in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the built-in [bitwise operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx) to examine the column.  For example

```
select
    schema_option & 0x01 AS  GeneratesObjectCreation,
    schema_option & 0x02 AS  GenerateCustomSP,
... etc.
```

Comment: This results in the following `Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 62
The data types binary and varbinary are incompatible in the '&' operator.`